# Verbs which do not admit of progressive action

Tags: tense, present-tense, aspect

> - she **stands**/ **is standing** in the shade of a tree.
>     (*is standing* is correct.)
> - The temple **stands/ is standing** in the heart of the city.
>     (*stands* is correct).

As per grammar rules there are some verbs which are non progressive and that includes **stand** as well.
In the above two sentences how do we apply that rule.
Why **is standing** is wrong in second sentence and correct in first?
Looking at the sentence I know they are to be used in that manner only but I want to correct myself with the grammar rules.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You might be interested in this page: **[lexical aspect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexical_aspect)**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's the distinction when using the *present simple* and *present continuous*.

The first sentence uses *is standing* since it's a temporary action, then you use the present continuous. (You don't stand in the shade unless you usually do it.)

The present simple is used for regular actions, habits or true facts, as shown in the second example.

Answer (score 0):

The first sentence is temporary there for stands is wrong.and not linking to speaker there for standing is correct

But second sentence is permanent there for stands is correct

Comment: Can you edit this to explain further? It is rather hard to see what your point is and as far as the first sentence it does not seem quite right.